# problem with adding self signed certificate Opentelemetry TLS

Tags: asp.net, ssl, grpc, open-telemetry, jaeger

We have a logging setup with Opentelemetry and visualise the logs in Jaeger. The export protocol used between the different entities is gRPC. We got the whole setup working but now we are tasked to enable TLS. Since the application has to run on premise we have to use self signed certificates. We tried setting it up but once TLS is enabled we get no logs and no errors that show what's going wrong.

We generated the certificates in OpenSSL with the following command:

`openssl req -new -nodes -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain.key -out domain.crt -config C:/Certs/san.cnf -extensions v3_req`

This is the corresponding config file:

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = DE
ST = 
L = Hannover
O = DummyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = localhost
[v3_req]
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

This is the part in the collector-config.yaml file where we added the certificates:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:30009
        tls:
          cert_file: domain.crt
          key_file: domain.key
```

And this is the .NET client we use to generate the logging:

```
//Setup tracing
            var lovTraceProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .AddSource("OpenTelemetryCollector")
                .SetResourceBuilder(
                    ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                        .AddService(serviceName: "OpenTelemetryCollector"))
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .AddJaegerExporter(test => { test.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:14268"); test.Protocol =JaegerExportProtocol.HttpBinaryThrift; })
                .AddOtlpExporter(lovOplt =>
                {
                    lovOplt.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
                    lovOplt.Endpoint = new Uri("https://localhost:8866/");
                })
                .Build();
```

The Opentelemetry Collector starts perfectly fine and when I browse on Chrome to the endpoint where it runs, I get the 'Not Secure' warning which I expect with a self signed certificate. So I assumed the certificate was ok and https was enabled.

But I do get this error in my Otel Collector server:
`[Server #3] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = \"ServerHandshake(\\\"[::1]:64328\\\") failed: remote error: tls: unknown certificate\""`

I think that it has something to do with the Otel Collector not accepting the self signed certificate. I already set up a different project where I had to enable TLS on a gRPC connection, and there I had to enable this skip:

```
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
    HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
```

I'm not sure if this is the same issue in this situation and if so how we would implement this on the Otel Collector

Comment: This is an OTEL Collector question and can't be fixed by the collector's clients. For starters, you don't need TLS in a Docker/Kubernetes environment where connections between services only happen based on the cluster/docker configuration. Second, the certificate *must* be trusted by *the containers*, not the applications in the containers. A self-signed certificate is invalid by definition, even if it was explicitly trusted on the machine it was created on.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/config/configtls/README.md

> Additionally you can configure TLS to be enabled but skip verifying the server's certificate chain. This cannot be combined with insecure since insecure won't use TLS at all.
>
> insecure_skip_verify (default = false): whether to skip verifying the certificate or not.

Comment: This setting is only available for the exporter, not the receiver where we need tls enabled.

Comment: @TiboVh sure, but I don't understand where collector is connecting (localhost via ipv6 port 64328). It is not clear which collector you are using. That looks like default config is applied. Maybe self monitoring.

Comment: Our custom application is sending logs and traces to the otel collector, which then sends it to a jaeger backend. We don't want to activate TLS on the flow between otel collector and jaeger, but on the flow from our custom application to the opentelemetry collector.

Comment: @TiboVh why do you want that? Aren't the application and the OTEL collector in the same Docker/Kubernetes cluster? The reason you don't find a lot of examples with TLS in OTEL Collector is that app/collector communications typically happen over a closed network, eg app/sidecar, or apps in a cluster

Comment: Our application has to run on premise and we aren't able to use Docker. That's why we want to secure the receiver with TLS since that will be the only port that we expose outside the local VLAN where OTEL is running.